# .Net 6 API with Windows Auth hosted on IIS throws CORS errors. Kestrel works fine

Tags: .net, cors, iis-express, iis-10

I've been trying for 3 days now to get my .Net Core API to run correctly under IIS or Express. The whole package works fine using Kestrel (or when debugging), but I can't make it work with IIS or Express. It's like whack-a-mole, solve one problem create two more.

As things stand now, the Web UI can receive GET requests, but the PUT, POST and DELETE are failing. I would for love someone to help me figure out what I've done wrong here.

Thank you in advance

## Error

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44369/api/documents/1' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

**Network Tab as two errors**

```
Request URL: https://localhost:44369/api/documents/1
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
-----------
Request URL: https://localhost:44369/api/documents/1
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:44369
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

### Program.cs

I'm leaving out the swagger bits and my references to `AddDbContxt(...)`

```
    ...
    var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
    builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
        options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins, policy =>
        {
            // I've tried using .AllowAnyOrigin() instead of WithOrigins but,
            // you can't use that with AllowCredentials or you get an error.
            policy.WithOrigins(
                "http://localhost:3000", "https://localhost:3000",
                "http://localhost:3001", "https://localhost:3001")
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials(); 
        }));
    ...
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();

    builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;

        var adminGroups = "DOAMIN\\GROUPC,DOMAIN\\GROUPD";
        var updateGroups = "DOMAIN\\GROUPB,DOMAIN\\GROUPC";
        var readGroups = "DOMAIN\\GROUPA";
        options.AddPolicy("Admin", p => p.RequireRole(adminGroups.Split(',')));
        options.AddPolicy("Update", p => p.RequireRole(updateGroups.Split(',')));
        options.AddPolicy("Read", p => p.RequireRole(readGroups.Split(',')));
    });
    ...
    // I've tried using forwardHeaders, but that didn't seem to help either
    //app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
    //{
    //     ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
    //});
    ...
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.MapControllers();

    app.Run();
```

### DocumentsController.cs

```
namespace org.proj.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [EnableCors("_myAllowSpecificOrigins")]
    [ApiController]
    public class DocumentsController : ControllerBase
    {
    ...
}
```

### web.config

I have tied the web config will all kinds of variations, none of them seem to improve the situation. Sometime they add double the origin heading. I've tried with the web.config and without the `useCors(...)` but none of it seems to make a difference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.webServer>
            <handlers>
                <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
            </handlers>
            <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\ct-net-ret-api.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
            <!--<httpProtocol>
                <customHeaders>
                    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="https://ctnet20retirement" />
                    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
                    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
                    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
                </customHeaders>
            </httpProtocol>-->
            <!--<security>
                <requestFiltering>
                    <verbs>
                        <remove verb="OPTIONS"/>
                        <add verb="OPTIONS" allowed="true"/>
                    </verbs>
                </requestFiltering>
            </security>-->
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

### launchSettings.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:46307",
      "sslPort": 44369
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    // This profile works
    "ct_net_ret_api": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7210;http://localhost:5210",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    // This profile only processes GET requests
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use failed request tracking to view detailed error information, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I am in the exact same situation